# How to avoid modifying permissions on a file every time I start my computer

Tags: permissions, serial-port

My serial port is located at `/dev/ttyUSB0`, and every time I want to access it after waking up my computer or starting it (Ubuntu 12.04), I have to run `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0` to grant myself access to the serial port.

Is there any way to give myself access to it by default? This is getting very annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that all /dev/tty* are owned by root.tty, so you could add yourself to the tty group.

Comment: Do you have any more instruction on how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @capcom `sudo adduser <user> tty` will add `<user>` to the group `tty`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/ttyUSB0 permission denied　【access your device permanently.】
```

Problem: /dev/ttyUSB0 permission denied.
You're not root, has no permission. Generally, do this way:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This isn’t very safe, strictly speaking, nor is it permanent. The change will need to be repeated every time you reboot the computer or unplug and reconnect the device.

```
 $ sudo usermod -aG dialout username
```

username is your username. Add this user into your dialout userGroup. Log out your linux and you can access your device permanently.